# How do I set the max width of flexbox content while allowing the container to keep growing?

Tags: css, flexbox

**Goals:**

- Dynamic number of items per row as the screen size changes
- As screen size increases, show a *max* number of *X* items per row and keep those items centered instead of growing them with the `.parent` container
- The scrollbar must remain at the max width of the `.parent` container.
- The width of child items should not increase
- Gaps between child items should not increase

**Restrictions:**

- Children must be *direct* children of the `div` with the scrollbar. Cannot add a `div` between them. (This is because the elements are auto-generated by a 3rd party toolkit.)
- Cannot change which element the scrollbar belongs to. It must be set on `.parent`.

Essentially, **this is what I want** on larger screens. However, I achieved this by adding a div between `.parent` and its children, which I can't do in the real code.
[image]

Here is my basic structure (without the intermediate div I'm not allowed to use):

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting a dynamic padding left and right on the parent div.

Add the following to the css rule for `.parent`:

```
  padding: 0 max(calc(50vw - 832px / 2), 20px);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

Adjust the max width of the area with the red boxes by changing the `832px` part to the width you would like. 832 gets you 8 boxes.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 max(calc(50vw - 832px / 2), 20px);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```